# Angular 6 - Using Observable to trigger event between siblings

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have a collection of divs in app-component filled with my `app-cube` components, and I have an array filled with `GridProp` objects in the parent component which's indexes represents each cell in the collection, meaning I create the content of each "cell" based on the content of array[i].

At array[i] I have an object with an Observable in it among other things like the content for cells. *When I update something in cell `i` I want to update the siblings of cell `[i-1]` and `[i+1]`*.

I am trying to do this by having each `app-cube` subscribe to the observable in the matching object in the array. This way I should be able to simply send a value to the observer in the array at any index and have it trigger the subscribed components subscription handler, right?

The objects in the array are of this class

```
export class GridProp implements OnInit {
  private terrain = new Terrain();
  coord: Array<number>;
  cont: {};

  observer: Observer<string>;
  observable: Observable<string> = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
    this.observer = observer;
  });
}
```

Then in the cube-component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cube',
  templateUrl: './cube.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cube.component.css']
})
export class CubeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() point; // Represents the relevant GridProp object

  ngOnInit() {
    this.point.observable.subscribe(this.handleCubeUpdate);
  }

  handleCubeUpdate() {
    console.log('handling!');
    this.updateWalls();
  }

  updateWalls() {
    // Do stuff to the "walls" values used in this cube.component.html
  }
  toggleWalls() {
    for (const direction in this.point.cont.terrain.walls) {
      if (this.getSide(direction) && this.getSide(direction).cont.terrain.isBlock) {
        this.point.cont.terrain.walls[direction] = false;
        this.getSide(direction).observer.next(true);
      } else {
        this.point.cont.terrain.walls[direction] = true;
      }
    }
    this.updateWalls();
  }
}
```

In the parent component I distrubte the app-cube

```
<div class="grid-point-z" *ngFor="let z of y">
  <div 
    class="grid-point"
    attr.data-point="{{ z.coord }}" 
    [ngStyle]="{ 
      'z-index': z.coord[2]
      }">
    <app-cube  
      [point]="z"
      [coord]="z"
      [level]="level"
      (click)="clickPoint(z)"
      (change)="onCubeChange($event)">
      {{z}}
    </app-cube>
  </div>
</div>
```

It crashes with the error

```
ERROR TypeError: this.updateWalls is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber.push../src/app/assets/cube/cube.component.ts.CubeComponent.handleCubeUpdate [as _next] (cube.component.ts:71)
```

So I guess it doesn't recognize `this.handleCubeUpdate` in the subscription in CubeComponent. Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: is that a function `updateWalls`? it seems to me that `handleCubeUpdate` is being called but look like `handleCubeUpdate` was calling `updateWall`.

Also, IMO, I'd use `Subject` in your `GridProp` component. 
```
    private subject = new Subject<string>();
    observable: Observable<string> = subject.asObservable();
```

Comment: Wops, thank you. I edited in the updateWalls function call. It is inside the handleCubeUpdate function. I changed the code as you described but the issue is the same. handleCubeUpdate is able to console.log "handling!", but the this.updateWalls(); is "is not a function" in the crash log

Comment: Where the updateWalls is declared ? And as @dK say, it is better to use Subject or BehaviorSubject.

Comment: And observable.subscribe declare the object which you subscribe observable.subscribe(p => console.log(p); }. And without next, your observable is useless.

Comment: The updateWalls is declared in cube.component.ts. It handles valued used in the HTML file. The .next() is also called later in the cube.component.ts, i'll add it to the post for clarity

Comment: then try `this.point.observable.subscribe(x => this.handleCubeUpdate);`

Comment: @User.Anonymous that seem to cause this.handlecubeUpdate to never fire

Comment: when you are using the observable next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view here we have kind of design problem.

In Angular, components can interact with each other using their `@Input()` and `@Output()` properties(Input - to be aware about changes from parent component and update view, Output - to notify others about changes inside).

So better to add to your `CubeComponent` output event `somethingChanged` and emit this event when, as you said, you update something.

```
export class CubeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() point; // Represents the relevant GridProp object
  @Output() somethingChanged = new EventEmitter<GridProp>();

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  notifyOthersComponentAboutUpdate() {
    let id = this.point; // You can emit point or some id, to identify it later in parent component
    this.somethingChanged.emit(id);
  }
}
```

In you parent component(`app-component`) which contains array of `app-cube` components create a method `updateSiblings(idOfComponentWhichWasUpdated)` and call it from `app-cube` component

```
<div class="grid-point-z" *ngFor="let z of y">
  <div 
    class="grid-point"
    attr.data-point="{{ z.coord }}" 
    [ngStyle]="{ 
      'z-index': z.coord[2]
      }">
    <app-cube  
      [point]="z"
      [coord]="z"
      [level]="level"
      (somethingChanged)="updateSiblings($event)">
      {{z}}
    </app-cube>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in that `updateSiblings` method your have access to your `y` array(`*ngFor="let z of y"`) which contains all data for `app-cube` components(`y: GridProp[]`).
You have id of component which was updated, so you can find it in array `y` and you can find his siblings and update their data as well. Angular will automatically detect changes in that `y` array and your siblings will be updated on UI level.

Comment: I ended up using your solution. I kept an observable in the GridProp where i manage the rendering of the "walls", and used the parent component to trigger the observable of any sibling of a clicked point including 'this' point, leaving each context intact. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear that. Happy to help @NachoDawg

Answer (score 2):

Now it make more sense to me that I could try to answer it here.
Hopefully I could articulate `this` properly :).

So, when you pass in a function reference in your `subscribe`, `this` in `handleCubeUpdate` has a different context. 
You can change your function implementation to arrow function.

```
handleCubeUpdate = () => {
  this.updateWalls();
}
```

additionally, if your `updateWalls` is calling another function, then you should change that `updateWalls` function arrow function.

Comment: Accepted answer. This allows me to reach the siblings by triggering their corresponding observables like i wanted to, thanks.

Comment: Actually it doesn't entirely work like i thought. While I manage to trigger the observable of a sibling, 'this' refers to the original point. I changed all the functions touched by handleCubeUpdate to arrow functions, but they always seem to refer to the point that triggered the sibling to update the walls

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a REDUX architecture in Angular?

[Here's a good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEcdQR-NoNA) on how it works and the benefits. I have used the exact same tutorial to learn about it and implement.

You could then keep that array in your store and dispatch actions to change thing. Each action could contain the logic to update itself + the two items surrounding it.